# Aspnet mvc4 webapi cause workerprocess crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with WebAPI on asp.net mvc4 site, the error message is:

You must write an attribute 'type' = 'object' after writing the attribute with local name '__type'.

the stack is:

```
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

My method return an object list IEnumerable , product is datacontract serializable without any problem

I recovered this error via a global error handler, when it happens the application is recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the suggestions [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1773173.aspx/1)?  They do all appear to be related to serialization (not using the `virtual` keyword, specifying known types, etc.).

I'd actually recommend not doing what the people in the post are describing, which is using entities direct from their DB context and not turning them into some sort of response model, for a few reasons:

- If your entity changes, you've potentially **broken your contract** with any consumers of your WebAPI
- If you wanted to transform any of the values after coming from the context, you're forced to do it in the controller, which kind of sucks because i**t gives the controller the added responsibility of mapping and transformation** ([AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is best for this)
- As sort of a combination of the first two points, you have coupled the persistence model concerns with the "view" (or in this case, contract) concerns (i.e., you aren't free to change your entity without worrying about the contract, and vice versa)

Not sure if you're doing any of those things without seeing more code, but it might help to make the model you are trying to use in the ApiController as [POCO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681329.aspx)-y as possible.

Comment: Thanks Brandon for your reply. the model is visible at http://erpstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/88814#2171145, I dont use EntityFramework.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the API controller action that breaks?  Is it just calling that one operation that makes the site break?  Does it break whether you request it as XML or JSON?

Comment: Not the exception is not systematic , the caller :

   var client = new HttpClient();
  T result = default(T);
  client.GetAsync(requestUri).ContinueWith((task) =>
  {
    HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
     response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().ContinueWith((readTask) =>
     {
      result = readTask.Result;
     }).Wait();
    }
    else
    {
     throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
  }).Wait();
the WebApiController is here :
http://erpstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/90030#2171287